# Jasmin SpyOn.and.returnValue() is not working with service call

Tags: angular, unit-testing, observable, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

In component I have one method which is actually calling service method from inside and in that method I am subscribing result of service response.
But while testing I used `SpyOn.and.returnValue` method so now it's not calling to service method but I am not getting response. It's always calling subscribe error block.

Here is my Test file code:

```
it('should check getMVRData method', inject([WorkflowService, PersonalDataService], (workFlow: WorkflowService, personalDataService: PersonalDataService) => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PersonalDataComponent);
    let inst = fixture.componentInstance;
    spyOn(personalDataService, 'getMVRData').and.returnValue(Observable.of(WORKFLOW_DATA));
    inst.getMVRData();

    // After sometime I am checking my console
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(inst.value);
        console.log(personalDataService.value)

    }, 1001);
}));
```

Here is my component code:

```
// Get License Data
value = 'subscribe data'
getMVRData() {
    this.value = 'inside get mvr method';
    this._personalDataService.getMVRData().subscribe(response => {
        let data = JSON.parse(response._body);
        this.value = 'inside success';
    }, error => {
        // This block is calling always
        this.value = 'inside error'
    });
}
```

Here is my service file method:

```
value: any;
getMVRData(): Observable < any > {
    this.value = 'inside service';
    let action = this.mvrConfig['action'];
    return this._authHttp.get(AppConfig.API_ENDPOINT() + action + '/?t=' + new Date(), this.headerOptions)
        .map(this._extractData)
        .map(this._doAction)
        .catch(this._handleError);
}
```

Service file method is not getting the call, that's working fine. But `returnValue` of `spyOn` function is not working properly.

Answer (score -3):

You have to call the **subscribe** method of the Observable you are returning here:

```
spyOn(personalDataService, 'getMVRData').and.returnValue(Observable.of(WORKFLOW_DATA));
```

**your.testfile.ts** (and check any value you are interested)

```
it('should check getMVRData method', inject([WorkflowService, PersonalDataService], (workFlow: WorkflowService, personalDataService: PersonalDataService) => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PersonalDataComponent);
    let inst = fixture.componentInstance;
    spyOn(personalDataService, 'getMVRData').and.returnValue(Observable.of(WORKFLOW_DATA));

    inst.getMVRData().subscribe(value => {
      console.log(value);
      expect(value).toEqual('It matchs');
    });        
}));
```